# ASP.NET MVC 4 Remember page index

Tags: pagination, asp.net-mvc-4

In a ASP.NET MVC 4 app I have a view with a paged list (just a simple table, no telerik grid or anything like that). New values are fetched from the database when the user pages through the list.

On every row in that table there is an edit button, when clicking the button you are presented with an edit view and when you click save in that view you are redirected back to the view with the paged list.

The urls for the list view looks like this

```
http://localhost/Items/Page/1
http://localhost/Items/Page/2
```

The route looks like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ItemsList",
        url :"Items/Page/{page}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Items", action = "Index", page = 1 },
            constraints: new {page = @"\d+"}
        );
```

My question is this: what is the preferred, most common way to store away the referring url, so when done editing an item, I can redirect the user back to the correct url

```
http://localhost/Items/Page/2
```

and not just to

```
http://localhost/Items
```

I've tried splitting up

```
Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery
```

and storing those values around, and then build the url from those values but I have a feeling there is a much better solution to this problem. Any suggestions?

**Update**

Right now I'm thinking that I could put the UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery (if there are any values) as a property on the view model for the edit screen and then use that when deciding on where to redirect after a save.

Any thoughts out there on that approach?

Comment: Is the paged list the only way in to the edit page?  Would you ever go back to some other controller/action?

Comment: Yes, you can get to the edit screen from several places in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my final solution to the problem, it's not super elegant but it works.
I added a property to the View model that could store the url. That value get's stored in a hidden field.

```
public class SkillEditModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RedirectBackToUrl { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller Edit(GET) method I store the value with the view model

```
if (!Request.UrlReferrer == null)
{
    model.RedirectBackToUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery;
}
```

And finally after saving the changes in Edit (POST) I did this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.RedirectBackToUrl))
{
    return new RedirectResult(model.RedirectBackToUrl);
}

return RedirectToAction("Index");
```